Adding a regression plane to plot_ly 3d plot
I have a multiple regression that plots well in plot_ly, however I cannot seem to get a regression line from ggpredict of a GLMM to overlay.
The model I want plotted is structured as the following:
my.lm <- glmmTMB(z ~ a * b + x + y + (1|g), data = MSdf, family = beta_family()), 

where a and b are categorical binomials (0 or 1) and x and y are continuous numeric variables (density gradients).
So far I have the following which makes a nice scatterplot:
p = plot_ly(x = ~x,
            y = ~y,
            z = ~z,
            type = "scatter3d",
            size = 1)

I want to add the predicted fit:
predic = ggpredict(my.lm, terms = c('x', 'y'), type = 'fixed') 

to the above scatterplot. Add_surface seems to be the best bet, but my z value is a vector rather than a numeric matrix, which is odd becuase in the examples I see, their z value is a vector. In other words, I get this error: Error: z must be a numeric matrix. I've tried a bunch of things to structure this matrix (i.e. z = as.numeric(Emig) %>% z = as.data.frame(z); cbind(x,y,z) to name a couple) but nothing seems to work.
I've done the same with scatterplot3d and it yields another issue the same issue.

You are right, add_surface is the way to do this. Here is how you can achieve this. Note I just added some sample data:
library(glmmTMB)
library(ggeffects)
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

set.seed(123)
n <- 100
MSdf <- data.frame(
  z = rbeta(n, 2, 5),
  a = sample(0:1, n, replace = TRUE),
  b = sample(0:1, n, replace = TRUE),
  x = runif(n, 0, 10),
  y = runif(n, 0, 10),
  g = factor(sample(1:10, n, replace = TRUE))
)

my.lm <- glmmTMB(z ~ a * b + x + y + (1|g), data = MSdf, family = beta_family())

x_seq <- seq(min(MSdf$x), max(MSdf$x), length.out = 100)
y_seq <- seq(min(MSdf$y), max(MSdf$y), length.out = 100)
common_g <- names(sort(table(MSdf$g), decreasing = TRUE))[1]  
grid <- expand.grid(x = x_seq, y = y_seq, a = unique(MSdf$a), b = unique(MSdf$b), g = common_g)

grid$z <- predict(my.lm, newdata = grid, type = "response")
grid_avg <- grid %>%
  group_by(x, y) %>%
  summarize(z = mean(z), .groups = 'drop')

z_matrix <- matrix(grid_avg$z, nrow = length(x_seq), ncol = length(y_seq))

p <- plot_ly(MSdf, x = ~x, y = ~y, z = ~z, type = "scatter3d", mode = "markers", marker = list(size = 2))
p <- p %>% add_surface(x = x_seq, y = y_seq, z = z_matrix)
p


Which gives


Thank you Serge. This code works and the graphs look beautiful!

Glad it helped.  If it is what you were looking for,  do mark the answer as accepted so it disappears from the list of unanswered questions.  Happy coding.
